# Angular and ASP.NET error, can't launch the webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular

I wrote a simple ASP.NET Web API. Then in cmd, in typed `ng new` and Angular files were created.

I opened the folder in VS Code and typed `ng serve --open` in the terminal.

I have the latest Angular, npm, node, VS Code, Visual Studio versions and checked all compatibilities. I reinstalled Angular, node, npm for like a few times.

Then I got these messages

```
Application bundle generation complete. [3.392 seconds]
Watch mode enabled. Watching for file changes...
  ➜  Local:   http://localhost:4200/
Vite Error, /@fs/C:/Users/1/Desktop/C#/ASP NET/AngularWebApi/PaymentApplication/.angular/cache/17.0.6/vite/deps/@angular_platform-browser.js?v=4241c9d8 optimized info should be defined
Vite Error, /@fs/C:/Users/1/Desktop/C#/ASP NET/AngularWebApi/PaymentApplication/.angular/cache/17.0.6/vite/deps/@angular_router.js?v=4241c9d8 optimized info should be defined
Vite Error, /@fs/C:/Users/1/Desktop/C#/ASP NET/AngularWebApi/PaymentApplication/.angular/cache/17.0.6/vite/deps/@angular_core.js?v=4241c9d8 optimized info should be defined
Vite Error, /@fs/C:/Users/1/Desktop/C#/ASP NET/AngularWebApi/PaymentApplication/.angular/cache/17.0.6/vite/deps/@angular_common.js?v=4241c9d8 optimized info should be defined
Vite Error, /@fs/C:/Users/1/Desktop/C#/ASP NET/AngularWebApi/PaymentApplication/.angular/cache/17.0.6/vite/deps/@angular_router.js?v=4241c9d8 optimized info should be defined
Vite Error, /@fs/C:/Users/1/Desktop/C#/ASP NET/AngularWebApi/PaymentApplication/.angular/cache/17.0.6/vite/deps/@angular_core.js?v=4241c9d8 optimized info should be defined
Failed to load url C:/Users/1/Desktop/C#/ASP NET/AngularWebApi/PaymentApplication/node_modules/vite/dist/client/env.mjs (resolved id: C:/Users/1/Desktop/C#/ASP NET/AngularWebApi/PaymentApplication/node_modules/vite/dist/client/env.mjs) in C:/Users/1/Desktop/C. Does the file exist?
```

Comment: _"in C:/Users/1/Desktop/C. Does the file exist?"_ I would put money on the `#` in the file path messing things up!

Comment: ok, but what about 'Vite Error'?

Comment: They also hint at missing optimization ino and may also be caused the inability to read the files. Try moving your code to a file path without any spaces or "special" characters and retry. If the Vite errors remain then it's something different. It's usually better to change one thing at a time.